# How to splitting a dataframe into parts by specific values of a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pandas` dataframe matrix that looks like this:

```
  Store Sales   year  month day
0   1   5263    2015    7   31
1   1   5020    2015    7   30
2   1   4782    2015    7   29
3   2   5011    2015    8   28
4   2   6102    2015    9   27
[986159 rows x 5 columns]
```

I need to split the data up into by removing the month where the value is 8 and 9. Then I need the rest of the training data to be in the other set.

I could do it like this but it doesn't work:

```
# Dataframe with 8 and 9 months
train_X1 = train[train['month'] == 9 or train['month'] == 8]
# The rest of the data
train_X2 = train[train['month'] != 9 or train['month'] != 8]
```

I could do this but that only gets me one part of the data with 8 and 9 month but the rest isn't captured:

```
train8 = train[train['month'] == 8]
train9 = train[train['month'] == 9]
train89 = train8 + train9
```

**How do I split `dataframe` the into 2 parts where one of it has specific values without splitting it twice?** (maybe with `dataframe.query()` or `pandas.train_test_split()`?)

Comment: You want to use `if with and` here `if train[train['month'] != 9 and train['month'] != 8: train_X2 = train[train['month']  ` I don't know if that solves the problem though. I haven't used pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of the operation is incorrect, replace the above split with the following.  You also need to wrap each predicate in parens and use '|' (or) and '&' (and).  This will perform the appropriate splits.

```
train_X1 = train[(train['month'] == 9) | (train['month'] == 8)]
train_X2 = train[(train['month'] != 9) & (train['month'] != 8)]
```

Comment: Just a short question, python keywords such as `or` and `and` is not useable in this pandas scenario right? And also `&&` and `||`?

Comment: You can't use && or || - they aren't valid python operations.  'or' and 'and' don't work because you're actually comparing two pandas Series with a boolean type.  checkout what train['month'] == 9 gives you.

Comment: Thanks @JonahWilliams !!